# Find interval for existence and uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> The interval where the solution to the initial value problem
> [image]
>
> exists and is unique, is:
>
> [image]

I began by solving for $y'$ which gave:
$$y' = \frac{t}{\ln t} - \frac{1}{(t-3)\ln t}*y$$

by looking at this I would say that $t≠1,3$ since $\ln(1)=0$ and $(3-3)\ln(3)=0$

So by this, the interval should not be $(a)$ or $(b)$ however, the correct answer is $(a)$ and I don't understand how that is possible.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: The interval should not contain $1$ nor $3$, contain $2$ and be contained in $\mathbf R^+. Which proposed answer satisfies these conditions?

Comment: Where is the $y$ in your equation?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry, I forgot the $y$

Comment: @Bernard But the correct answer is that the interval is $(1,3)$..

Comment: Yes, it is the only interval satisfying all three conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put the ODE in standard form

$$\frac{dy}{dt} + P(t)y = Q(t)$$

which in your case is

$$\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{1}{(t-3)\ln(t)}y = \frac{t}{\ln(t)}$$

and then observe the intervals in which $P(t)$ and $Q(t)$ exist and are continuous. Note that both $P(t)$ and $Q(t)$ are undefined for $t=1$. For $$P(t)=\frac{1}{(t-3)\ln(t)}$$

the domain of $t$ is $(0,1)\cup(1,3)\cup(3,\infty)$. For $$Q(t)=\frac{t}{\ln(t)}$$

the domain of $t$ is $(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$. So, the combined interval of continuity for both $P(t)$ and $Q(t)$ is the restricted domain of $(0,1)\cup(1,3)\cup(3,\infty)$.

The initial condition at $t=2$ is given as $y(2)=0$. This matches one specific part of the combined interval of continuity which is given as the answer $(a)$.